# LibGDX: Error making a socket connection to *ip-adress*

Tags: sockets, tcp, libgdx

I want to make 2 devices communicate via sockets.
I use this code for the client socket:

```
Socket socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, adress, 1337, socketHints);
```

(SocketHints: timeout = 4000)

I get a GdxRuntimeException each time this line is being executed. What is wrong with the socket?

[Screenshot of stack trace](https://prnt.sc/g25yr3)

Comment: Any reason not to use [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet)?

Answer (score 0):

You get that message because the socket couldn't be opened.

Note the last line about the return [in the API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html#newClientSocket-com.badlogic.gdx.Net.Protocol-java.lang.String-int-com.badlogic.gdx.net.SocketHints-):

> **newClientSocket**:
>
> ```
> Socket newClientSocket(Net.Protocol protocol,
>                        java.lang.String host,
>                        int port,
>                        SocketHints hints)
>
> Creates a new TCP client socket that connects to the given host and port.
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>     host - the host address
>     port - the port
>     hints - additional SocketHints used to create the socket. Input null to use the default setting provided by the system.
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
>     GdxRuntimeException in case the socket couldn't be opened
> ```

Try doing some debugging to find out why you are getting this error.

Is the port already in use? Are you trying to open more than one connection on the same port? Is the server IP valid? Maybe something else is causing the issue?

Comment: i tried to use a different port, same problem.
i am using the java socket instead of the libgdx and it works for me

Comment: So if a normal java socket works, then what is different? I suspect that your libgdx application attempts to perform a networking operation in the main thread. Make sure networking is done in a different thread. Without seeing more code I can only try and guess what is wrong.